# Odd-looking circle

Tags: visual, lateral-thinking, geometry

A man is told to make a circle

He makes this:

[image]

Where is the man?

Comment: And this is an even-looking circle: ⃝.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> In Manhattan, because that is what a "circle" (defined to be the set of points of a certain set distance d away from a given point) looks like when using the [taxicab (or Manhattan) metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry#Circles).

Answer (score 53):

He has made a rapid escape from the scene because he actually didn't know what a "circle" was.

No wait.

> He **makes** it.
>
>
>
> Well, he *draws* a circle.
>
>  [image]
>
>  And then he *makes* the diamond...
>
>  [image]
>
>  
> So where is the man?
>
>  
> Think what I have just done.
>
>  
> I **am** that man.

Comment: That's a..... _cheeky_ ..... answer :)

Comment: But we still don’t know where you are!   :-)   ⁠

Answer (score 29):

Clearly the man is

> in [$L^1$ space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space).

He was asked to draw a *circle*, namely the set of all points at distance $1$ from a fixed centre.

> We imagine this as looking round, because we live in Euclidean $L^2$ space. But this man lives in $L^1$ space, in which the unit circle is a square box because the concept of 'distance' is defined differently. More generally, unit circles in $L^p$ space look like this for assorted values of $p$:
>
>  [image: unit discs]

Comment: So he could also be in L^inf space, just with is head tilted?

Comment: @Tilefish Well yes.

Answer (score 0):

He's in another distance metric, one where distance is determined by the addition of coordinates, instead of pythagorean theorem.