# A different circle

Tags: word, wordplay

Inspired by [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/60441/odd-looking-circle), but different.

A woman is told to make a circle

She makes...

[image]

...bread!

Where is the woman? And where is she from?

Hint:

> Note that `geometry` is not in the tags

Hint2:

> There are multiple answers. And probably `language` should be in the tags.

---

image by *fir0002/flagstaffotos.com.au* published under [GFDL 1.2](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/fdl-1.2.html), via Wikimedia Commons

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/panis#/media/File:Breads.jpg says you must provide attribution if you use that image. Please respect copyrights when creating puzzles.

Comment: @Bass thanks for the reminder, it slipped my mind...

Comment: To be super pedantic, does she just make "bread", or does she make two loaves that look just like those two?

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner It's just an illustration - any generic bread would do.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inspired by [rhsquared's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/60519/45235), I'd guess the woman is from

> Slovenia

and is in

> Slovakia

Explanation:

> Kruh is Slovak for circle and Slovene for bread.
>  (also Czech, but Slovenia/Slovakia IMO best fits the wordplay tag)
>  Source: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kruh (being native in Slovene might have helped me a bit though :))

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer (or one of them). It would also work with Croatian on one side and (spoken) Belarussian (or those variants of Russian where г is pronounced [ɦ]) on the other. I considered excluding sk/sl/hr/cs speakers from the answering, but that would have been a *big* hint.

Answer (score 10):

She is in:

> South Africa or Lesotho

And she speaks:

> Xhosa or Zulu

Why?

> Bread is "isonka" in Xhosa.
>  Circle is "isangqa" in Xhosa.
>  Bread is "isinkwa" in Zulu, another language from the same place.

So:

> When somebody told her to make isangqa, she didn't heard clearly and understood that she was asked for isonka or isinkwa instead.
>  Since there are several different dialects of Xhosa and Zulu languages in different regions of South Africa, it is very plausible that miscomunication happens between similar sounding words.

Comment: Very good thinking, this is *not* among those multiple possible answers I had in mind

Comment: I actually think this is quite unlikely, since the "ngq" in *isangqa* actually represents the phoneme [ŋ̊!ʰ], a kind of "nasal click" that sounds *very* different to [k].

Comment: In fact it's [ŋ!ʱ]* sorry

Answer (score 7):

My answer is based on an assumption about the native language of the author.
She is in:

> Croatia (most likely )or Slovenia

And she speaks:

> Croatian or Slovenian

because in these languages:

> Croatian Bread-Circle = Kruh-Krug and in Slovenian Bread-Circle=Kruh-Krog. Most likely Croatian.

Close enough to mislead you.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I give my first try here, here's what came into my mind, guess I'm not even close though:

> she has been told to make a circle, *pain circle* is a kind of circle, so she made *pain* (bread in french), so I guess the woman is from France, and she is in a hospital (maybe she works as a cook)

Comment: How did she make the bread if she's in a hospital?

Comment: maybe she works as a cook in the hospital

Comment: Welcome to SE Puzzling! Would you elaborate more on your answer?

Comment: I don't really see how I could elaborate more

Comment: I don't understand your answer. What is a "pain circle"? Does that phrase mean something specific in English or French or both?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis mmmh it's'true i get almost no results with "pain circle" on google, I tried with the French "cercle de la douleur" and got many results. That is a vicious circle: if you feel pain you will avoid activity, so you will lose physical condition, so you will be more likely to get hurt and feel pain.

Comment: @Flying_whale you are, well, not *that* close, but at least in the general geographical area :-)